# Docker Wordpress not connecting with docker Mysql Compose

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, nginx, proxy

I am trying to set up multiple WordPress sites being hosting on the same server using docker using nginx reverse proxy server. I have a network setup with the nginx proxy listening on port 80 called nginx-proxy. I confirmed they are all on the same docker network. However, I am still getting WordPress is unable to communicate with the database. I can confirm that the credentials are correct and that MySQL is running on the other docker container.

With my testing, the forwarding proxy is working if I update the virtual host and open it in the web browser it does open the error message on that page. I can ping both the containers from within their shell. I am not sure what I am doing wrong I am newer to dockers networking within version 3. I don't believe docker has differenced between platforms, but in case it does I am running it on Mac OS.

I know there are other posts similar to this using Link and version 2 however, I was not able to find a version 3 with information that fixed my issue.

```
version: "3.3"

    services:
       db_node_domain:
         image: mysql:5.7
         volumes:
           - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
         restart: always
         environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
           MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
           MYSQL_USER: wordpress
           MYSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
         container_name: wordpress_db

       wordpress:
         depends_on:
           - db_node_domain
         image: wordpress:latest
         expose:
           - 80
         restart: always
         environment:
           VIRTUAL_HOST: domain.com
           WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_node_domain:3306
           WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
           WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
         container_name: wordpress
    volumes:
        db_data: {}

    networks:
      default:
        external:
          name: nginx-proxy
```

Please let me know if any more information is required. Thank you for any assistance you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your docker-compose file, also it's working on my local machine which is macOS.
One thing, 'wordpress' container will fail to bring up several times with `MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused` on the first bootup due to MySQL initialization. It should connect to 'wordpress_db' after a few retrials.
If it doesn't connect even after retrials, can you attach logs of 'wordpress' container?

Comment: Hello hwwwi, 

I gave it some time and a few restarts. MySQL is running correctly. It is almost like there is an issue with the docker DNS. Here are my docker logs for the WordPress docker container. Please let me know if there is a different log I need to be pulling. 

https://pastebin.com/54KLgnyx

I am also getting this status from the MySQL server 
[info] MySQL Community Server 5.7.30 is running.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the docker network on my mac. I ran this code on my test server vs my local development machine and it worked. I am not sure how to go about troubleshooting this issue to fix it though. A bit irritating I didn't try it on the server earlier and saved myself 8 hours of trying without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as your docker compose file below.

Reference:
https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/wordpress-mysql

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.19
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: This would not accomplish what I am trying to do. As it would bind the 80 port of the container to the computer. Which would currently b in conflict with the proxy. My goal is to have them isolated to one another and expose the 80 port for the Proxy to view not bind it. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I have isolated the issue. It was the first time I was playing the docker volumes. I forgot to clear out the volumes when I updated the database information. So I was connecting to the old database with the new information which was leading to the error (This is why your don't try to learn something new late into the night on little sleep). Once I removed the volumes recomposed the docker containers it works perfectly.

Thank you for every one who assisted me with this.